# Generate different name of text file at every hit

Tags: python, md5

I have an endpoint hosted in ec2 machine. This endpoint has a piece of code that has to generate a text file.
I want that if multiple people are hitting this endpoint, then this snippet should generate different text file name for each of them.

I tried using md5 hash in Python. but unable to append this hash value in the name of text file.

```
hash2 = random.getrandbits(128)
name = "test_data" + str(hash2)
sys.stdout = open(name.txt, "w")
```

Comment: `name.txt` is that a typo? You probably should try `name = "test_data" + str(hash2) + ".txt"` and when opening the file: `open(name, "w")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to open `name.txt`, where you should try to open `name`.

It is also not very often seen that you assign the `open()` value to `sys.stdout`. It is better to use a variable of your own (for instance: `fp`, `stream`) instead.